# Is there any dropdown option in django python which auto fill textbox by selection dropdown value from single table?

Tags: python, html, django, sqlite

| Id | Item name | Item Code |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Sensor | s001 |
| 2 | PCB | p034 |

input -

select dropdown- sensor

auto fill in textbox- s001

I am new to django python, please suggest me some methods.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have no idea what you are asking.

Comment: i want dropdown which select value (sensor) and auto fill textbox value( s001).